# Turning Recursive algorithm into breadth-first queue

Tags: ruby, algorithm, recursion, queue, breadth-first-search

So I am working with a "course". The course is full of coordinates. Each coordinate has attributes that allow movement(#left #right #up #down). The course is built upon a coordinate system so left would be x-1, right would be x+1, up would be y-1, and down would be y+1.

My goal is to get the shortest distance of each reachable coordinate. 
Distance is defined by the number of moves from the start point (the start coordinate of the course that is provided in the parameters). So the distance from (0,0) to (1,2) would be 3. 1 right and 2 down
I've originally solved this problem using recursion:

Answer: Rather than go through each one as far as as possible in depth, use an array to go through each of the paths within each difference at a time

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: You should correct the indentation.  That may show that there's an extra `end` in the second part. Also, it's a courtesy to readers to format the code so that it can be read without the need for horizontal scrolling (i.e., break long statements into multiple lines).

Comment: @IVlad I get a name error with Queue.new(), I'm not sure how to fix that part. I also am confident that it won't work once i fix that error because I don't know count the moves correctly

Comment: `However, this recursive algorithm takes too long to go through the large courses` - note that the complexity of depth first search and that of breadth first search are identical. If that's the only problem with your recursive search, it's unlikely you'll fix it just by changing to BFS.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Yes I will work on it. Sorry, It wasn't letting me cpy-paste from my editor so I had to type it all out. New to stackoverflow so the formatting is kid of weird

Comment: Please define what you mean by a "reachable coordinate". I'm guessing that this has to do with an undirected graph, where two nodes (coordinates) are joined by a link if the distance between them (suitably defined) is `1`. Also, you say you want the "shortest distance of each reachable coordinate". As well as defining "distance", you need to specify the location from which the distance to each coordinate is determined. Perhaps you mean the shortest distance between each pair of coordinates that are mutually "reachable". To me, this is sounding more and more like just a shortest path problem.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Each coordinate has directions it can go. left, right, up or down, much like a maze. So if a coordinate can't be reached from the start point, then it is unreachable

Comment: You need to define "start point", "distance", "reachable", etc. This is not a question of semantics; readers, including this one, have no idea what they mean.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I added further explanation to it, but I'm not sure how else to explain it. It's essentially a maze-course. You start at one point and can travel to different points relevant to the directions they allow. If you never reach a certain coordinate, then it's unreachable

Comment: It's worth noting that [`Queue`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/thread/rdoc/Queue.html) is a special class intended to be used to pass data between threads and is a poor substitute for `Array` when you're simply creating a stack.

Comment: @tadman yes. Changed to array, tutorials mislead me. thank-you

Answer (score 1):

Think of your problem as a undirected graph with the nodes being the coordinates, where each pair of (distinct) nodes `[x0,y0]` and `[x1,y1]` is "adjacent" if:

```
[x0-x1].abs <= 1 && [y0-y1].abs <= 1
```

Two nodes are connected by an undirected link if they are adjacent, in which case the length of that link is 1. If two nodes are connected by a path of nodes and links, the distance between them equals the sum of the lengths of the links on the path (i.e., the number of links in the path).

You can find the shortest distance between all pairs of coordinates by employing an algorithm that computes shortest paths between all pairs of nodes in an undirected graph, such as the [Floyd-Warshall algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm) (which also works for directed graphs).

Floyd-Warshall treats non-adjacent pairs of nodes as being connected by a link of infinite length (which may be implemented as a suitably large number). If the length of the shortest path between a given pair of nodes is found to be "infinite", you know the nodes are not connected (i.e., there is no path between the coordinates).